# return function is returning none after some recursion, not returnig what i want

Tags: python-3.x

I want to get input from player to choose in between 'X' and 'O', and want my function to return that 'X' or 'O', so i can process that value.but my function is not working properly.for 1st recurrence it returns correct value but for next or more recurrence call function it is returning Null.
please help me with that.

first i entered wrong input (Ex. C) and then correct required input which is 'X' or 'O'.according to me it should return 'X' or 'O' according to input.but it returning Null.

```
def getPlayerLetter():
    userLetter = input("Do you want to be 'X' or 'O'? ")
    if userLetter == 'X' or userLetter == 'O':
        return userLetter
    else:
        print("Wrong choice.try again...")
        getPlayerLetter()

letter = getPlayerLetter()
print(letter)
```

My Outputs.

```
Do you want to be 'X' or 'O'? C
Wrong choice.try again...
Do you want to be 'X' or 'O'? Y
Wrong choice.try again...
Do you want to be 'X' or 'O'? X
None
```

Comment: See this [question](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/python-function-returns-a-none-value-for-no-reason), too. The return value is discarded in recursive function.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `return` the result of `getPlayerLetter()`:

```
def getPlayerLetter():
    userLetter = input("Do you want to be 'X' or 'O'? ")
    if userLetter == 'X' or userLetter == 'O':
        return userLetter
    else:
        print("Wrong choice.try again...")
        return getPlayerLetter()

letter = getPlayerLetter()
print(letter)
```

Output:

```
Do you want to be 'X' or 'O'? C
Wrong choice.try again...
Do you want to be 'X' or 'O'? Y
Wrong choice.try again...
Do you want to be 'X' or 'O'? X
X
```